# Manual array sort returning nullpointerexception

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Anyone have any idea why this code is returning a nullpointerexception? It's supposed to sort an array alphabetically, but it's not performing that function.

```
public void borrowerSort() throws IOException {
        String inputFile = "Borrower Details.txt";
        String outputFile = "Borrower Details2.txt";

        FileReader txtArranger = new FileReader(inputFile);
        BufferedReader txtReader = new BufferedReader(txtArranger);



        for(int i = 0; i <= inputFile.length(); i ++)
        {
            borrowerDetails[i] = txtReader.readLine();
//      
//          System.out.println(borrowerDetails[i]);
//      System.out.println();
        }

        //System.out.println(borrowerDetails[0] + borrowerDetails[2]);
        for(int j = 0; j < borrowerDetails.length - 1; j ++)
        {
            for(int k = j + 1; k < borrowerDetails.length; k ++)
            {
                if(borrowerDetails[j].compareTo(borrowerDetails[k]) > 0){
                    String store = borrowerDetails[j];
                    borrowerDetails[j] = borrowerDetails[k];
                    borrowerDetails[k] = store;

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Without more context we can't really help you. There are numerous places in this code where a NullPointerException could occur. Which line exactly is the problem?

Comment: Do you need to write a custom sort? If not, consider using `Arrays.sort()`.

Comment: the array is declared at the beginning of the code, the line where the error is occurring is the one featuring compareTo.

Comment: I do unfortunately have to do a custom sort. :(

Comment: `inputFile.length()` is the number of character in the string literal `Borrower Details.txt`. In the loop that reads from the file, it is likely that there are less "borrows" than number of characters in the string, causing `txtReader.readLine()` to return `null`, cause a NPE when attempting to dereference the array element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    String inputFile = "Borrower Details.txt";

    for(int i = 0; i <= inputFile.length(); i ++)
    {
        borrowerDetails[i] = txtReader.readLine();
```

It is not possible to derive the size of a file in lines from the length of the **name** of the file.

Use a `List<String>` to read the lines, copy to an array and sort that.

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
while( (line = txtReader.readLine()) != null ){
    lines.add( line );
}
```

The reason for the NPE is due to the incorrect allocation for String[] borrowerDetails. If this array is longer than the number of lines (!) in the file, some array elements remain null, which causes NPE when `borrowerDetails[j].compareTo(...)` is called

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have fixed-size array of objects `borrowerDetails`, while your input txt files doesn't guarantee that this array is filled completely. Empty array of objects is initialized with nulls, so if you don't fill it completely, you finally end up trying to do something like `object.lenght > null` that causes NPE.
Please try to trace and check how completely it is being filled with `borrowerDetails[i] = txtReader.readLine();` cycle.